# Organizing classes in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've small problem with organizing some resources in my Rails app.
Let's say:

```
# app/models/bucket.rb
class Bucket < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I would like to add simple class to make some calculations over `Bucket` let's say:

```
class ItemsCalculator
end
```

and...

```
class ShippingCostCalculator
end
```

**How I'm supposed to organize these 3 classes having in mind logically relation with `Bucket`.**

I've a couple of options:

1)

```
app/models/bucket -> Bucket
app/models/bucket/items_calculator -> Bucket::ItemsCalculator
app/models/bucket/shipping_cost_calculator -> Bucket::ShippingCostCalculator
```

2)

```
app/models/bucket -> Bucket
lib/bucket/items_calculator -> ItemsCalculator
lib/bucket/shipping_cost_calculator -> ShippingCostCalculator
```

3)

```
app/models/bucket -> Bucket
lib/bucket/items_calculator -> Bucket::ItemsCalculator
lib/bucket/items_calculator -> Bucket::ShipingCalculator
```

What do you prefer, which version is most proper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models are what should handle the business logic of your application.  Models do not need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` to be a model. So these calculator classes sound like models to me.

So my opinion is that they go in `app/models`. But are they applicable in any general way? Or do they *only* apply to `Bucket`? If they only apply to `Bucket` then option 1 makes sense.

But if they apply to other models, or can be used standalone, I might recommend:

```
app/models/bucket -> Bucket
app/models/items_calculator -> ItemsCalculator
app/models/shipping_cost_calculator -> ShippingCostCalculator
```

---

But my hunch is that you want option 1.